# Java Apache POI Excel files mapping in Database Objects with something like HeaderColumn strategy?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My application allows the user in the FE to manually map the headerColumns to fields of the database. At least thats my intention and the target.

I did this for CSV files with OpenCSV and a `HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy` sucessfully. Now I want to do this for Excel files like .xls or .xlsx too.
The backend is using Spring Boot and gets the whole file and the mapping in form of a JSONArray. The columns can be of every single existing entity of the database: e.g. Article, Shop, Receipt or whatever. If a column named `EAN` has now the mapping Article.ean and maybe also a column named `Size` which is mapped to Article.size then an object of the class Article should be created and the rest of the fields of the class Article should be empty.

So all rows should be iterated and objects of the mapped types should be created and put into a list and then persisted into the database.

My attempt yet is to read all rows which works pretty well:

```java
     // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
     XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());

     // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
     XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

     // Iterate through each rows one by one
     Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
     while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
         Row row = rowIterator.next();
         // For each row, iterate through all the columns
         Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

         while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
             Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
             // Check the cell type and format accordingly
             switch (cell.getCellType()) {
             case NUMERIC:
                 System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                 break;
             case STRING:
                 System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                 break;
             case BLANK:
                 break;
             case BOOLEAN:
                 break;
             case ERROR:
                 break;
             case FORMULA:
                 break;
             case _NONE:
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
             }
         }
         System.out.println("");
     }
```

But I have no clue how to map every single cellValue to the mapping of my jsonArray. Something like `HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy` does not exist or am I blind?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it indirectly. I would recommend you to convert the Excel file (.xls or .xlsx) in CSV (local string) and do from the there the `HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy`.

Here is how I convert it to csv.

```java
     List<String[]> noDoubt = new ArrayList<>();

     StringWriter strWrt = new StringWriter();
     CSVWriter csvWrt = new CSVWriter(strWrt);

     InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream());

     XSSFWorkbook xlsxWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

     XSSFSheet xlsxWorksheet = xlsxWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

     Iterator<Row> rowIterator = xlsxWorksheet.iterator();

     while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
         Row row = rowIterator.next();
         int i = 0; //String array
         int noOfColumns = xlsxWorksheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
         String[] nextLine = new String[noOfColumns];

         Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
         while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
             Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
             switch (cell.getCellType()) {
             case STRING:
                 nextLine[i] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                 break;
             case BLANK:
                 break;
             case BOOLEAN:
                 break;
             case ERROR:
                 break;
             case FORMULA:
                 break;
             case NUMERIC:
                 String str = NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                 nextLine[i] = str;
                 break;
             case _NONE:
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
             }
             i = i + 1;
         }
         noDoubt.add(nextLine);
     }
     xlsxWorkbook.close();
     inputStream.close();
     csvWrt.writeAll(noDoubt);
     csvWrt.close();
     String finalString = strWrt.toString();

     // csv stuff following...
```

This code works only for .xlsx files! For .xls files use HSSF